# (Qt C++) ui Undeclared Identifier When in New Function

Tags: c++, qt, function, undeclared-identifier

:)

I am working on a project and I need to take a value (ui->SpawnX->value()) and put it into an int variable.

When I put:

```
temp_int = ui->SpawnX->value();
```

in

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSave_savegame_dat_triggered()
{
    int temp_int;
}
```

it runs flawlessly, however, I am going to have a lot of these so I want to put it in a simple function. So, above this I made:

```
void LevelWrite()
{
int temp_int;
    temp_int = ui->SpawnX->value();
}
```

But whenever I run it, I get an error saying "ui" : undeclared identifier

Any help would be wonderful :D

Thanks

Comment: Could `ui` be a data member of `MainWindow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have this

`private:
    void LevelWrite();`

in your .h file. Most likely you will just need to add the void LevelWrite() line underneath the already existent private: section of your .h file. And then in your .cpp file you will need to have

`void MainWindow::LevelWrite()`

Then you should be able to use `ui->` within your LevelWrite method. Hopefully this can also help someone else who is running into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your MainWindow is a typed herited from a QObject, right? So ui is a data you can access only in your class, that's why you can't access to it from your function LevelWriter, you can make an accessor like

```
void LevelWrite(MainWindow* window)
{
    int temp_int;
    temp_int = window->getUi()->SpawnX->value();
}
```

Or put LevelWriter in your MainWindow class.

Comment: I'm getting "getUi" is not a member of MainWindow, and more after that. I changed it to "ui" "Ui" with and without parenthesis. Nothing worked

Comment: That's because you must create this method. I'm sorry, I haven't been really clear. You have to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `LevelWrite` class member of `MainWindow` because `ui` is not a global variable but a class member of `MainWindow`.

Comment: I just guessed around a bit and added LevelWrite to the private section next to the others and then added MainWindow:: to LevelWrite

So my function was MainWindow::LevelWrite()

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it may be that you are using version 5.x and upwards, and have not added

QT += Widgets

at the top pf your .pro file. Check that too.